# Ordinal vs interval scales

Tags: statistics

I am reading about [mean reciprocal rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank) and I came across this remark:

> The major problem with MRR, however, is the following: as observed
> already in [19], the difference between ranks $1$ and $2$ is the same as
> that between ranks $2$ and $∞$. This means that RR is not an interval
> scale, it is only an ordinal scale. However, one
> cannot compute the mean for an ordinal scale! Only the median would be
> possible here — which would produce ties in most cases.

I get why the distance between ranks $1$ and $2$ is the same as between $2$ and $\infty$, that is because $1/1-1/2 = 1/2$ and $1/2-1/\infty = 1/2$. Why does this mean RR is an ordinal rather than an interval scale?

I can't really get my head around the mathematical definitions of the two types, and can only find vague statements online like 'interval scale is where .... the difference between two values is meaningful' under most of which MRR would seem to be fine.

The writer of that paper (http://sigir.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/p032.pdf) provided a reference to S.S. Stevens. On the theory of scales of measurement. Science, New Series
103(2684):677–680, June 1946. But I can't really understand what in this shows MRR is ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the Wikipedia example where the question is "what is the plural of *torus*?" and the guesses in order of belief are "*torii, tori, toruses*", then if *tori* is correct then the correct guess will be give a rank of $2$ and so a reciprocal rank score of $\frac12$.

This is independent of the degree of confidence in the various guesses: $51\%,48\%,1\%$ or $35\%,33\%,32\%$ or $97\%,2\%,1\%$ would all lead to the same reciprocal rank score of $\frac12$.  That is why it is seen as an ordinal scoring system rather than an interval scale or some other type scale; it is a score based only on rank position.

Comment: I don't think so. Have a look at the paper, http://sigir.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/p032.pdf. The author goes on to say immediately after that a possible fix is to use just ranks (not reciprocal ranks) and take their means--implying that'd be interval

Comment: @MobeusZoom Just using ranks rather than reciprocal ranks would also be ordinal-based, as by definition the same ranks (ordinal positions) would produce the same results.

Comment: Yeah read the paper. I don't think that's what ordinal vs interval means. Unless you think the author is wrong

Comment: @MobeusZoom Norbert Fuhr does not say the suggested MFR alternative is an "interval scale", while the mention of a "ratio scale" seems as if it might about effort in ranking rather than accuracy of particular rankings

Comment: I'm just trying to understand his reasoning why taking the mean of reciprocal rank is not valid. (But mean for MFR *is* valid.) I should say, I'm quite sure his statement that 'the difference between ranks 1 and 2 is the same as that between ranks 2 and ∞' doesn't generically apply to any ranks (e.g. 'the difference between ranks 1 and 2 is the same as that between ranks 2 and 10'). He chose those because the difference is numerically 1/2

Comment: In other words, I don't think degree of confidence has anything to do with it, because you could say the same for rank as for reciprocal rank. Yet he is fine with calling rank a 'ratio' (which you can take mean of), let alone interval, but insists reciprocal rank is not an interval